# How was the relationship between Ashwatthama and Arjuna?

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna, ashwatthama

Arjuna was the most favorite student of Dronacharya. Did Ashwatthama had the same type of relationship with Arjuna or was favorable to Kauravas and Duryodhana? I heard both versions. What does the Vyasa Mahabharata say about this?

Feel free to quote translations of MB in regional texts but not interpolations and baseless folklores.